# default lambda sequence in glmnet for cross-validation

Tags: glmnet, lasso-regression

Does anybody know how cv.glmnet (in R's glmnet) or LassoCV (scikit-learn) chooses a sequence of regularization constants (lambdas), which they use in cross-validation? Thank you very much!

Comment: (In R glmnet at least) Never use the default lambda sequence, this is known to be dangerous. Always supply your own sequence.

Comment: @smci Can you explain in what way / why the default lambda sequence in glmnet is dangerous? Thanks.

Comment: @visitor: "not necessarily guaranteed to find lambda which minimizes CVE". It might, it might not. Plot the deviance/log(lambda) curve to see if you found it. The advice I was always given was define your own lambda sequence, and tweak it if it's not good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Friedman, Hastie & Tibshirani (2010) 'strategy is to select a minimum value lambda_min = epsilon * lambda_max, and construct a sequence of K values of lambda decreasing from lambda_max to lambda_min on the log scale. Typical values are epsilon = 0.001 and K = 100.'

The following example generates data, calculates the lambda path and compares it to that of glmnet:

```
## Load library and generate some data to illustrate:
library("glmnet")
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*20), n, 20)
y <- rnorm(n)

## Standardize variables: (need to use n instead of (n-1) as denominator)
mysd <- function(z) sqrt(sum((z-mean(z))^2)/length(z))
sx <- scale(x, scale = apply(x, 2, mysd))
sx <- as.matrix(sx, ncol = 20, nrow = 100)

## Calculate lambda path (first get lambda_max):
lambda_max <- max(abs(colSums(sx*y)))/n
epsilon <- .0001
K <- 100
lambdapath <- round(exp(seq(log(lambda_max), log(lambda_max*epsilon), 
                            length.out = K)), digits = 10)
lambdapath

## Compare with glmnet's lambda path:
fitGLM <- glmnet(sx, y)
fitGLM$lambda
```

Note that glmnet does not compute solutions for all 100 (default) lambda values though, it stops earlier. Not sure what the rules for stopping are.

See also [How does glmnet compute the maximal lambda value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257780/how-does-glmnet-compute-the-maximal-lambda-value/)

---

Friedman, J., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2010). Regularization paths for generalized linear models via coordinate descent. *Journal of statistical software, 33*(1), 1.

Comment: It seems you normalize `y` vector and then compute `lambda_max`. According to package, `y` is only centered not scaled???

Comment: Indeed. But if you replace the line `sy <- as.vector(scale(y, scale = mysd(y)))` by `sy <- y`, the calculated `lambdapath` and `fitGLM$lambda` are still equal.

Comment: Omitted normalization of `y` now.