# How does glmnet compute the maximal lambda value?

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

The `glmnet` package uses a range of `LASSO` tuning parameters `lambda` scaled from the maximal `lambda_max` under which no predictors are selected. I want to find out how `glmnet` computes this `lambda_max` value. For example, in a trivial dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
library("glmnet")
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y <- rnorm(100)
fitGLM <- glmnet(x,y)
max(fitGLM$lambda)
# 0.1975946
```

The package vignette (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper) describes in section 2.5 that it computes this value as follows:

```
sx <- as.matrix(scale(x))
sy <- as.vector(scale(y))
max(abs(colSums(sx*sy)))/100
# 0.1865232
```

Which clearly is close but not the same value. So, what causes this difference? And in a related question, how could I compute `lambda_max` for a logistic regression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the same result you need to standardize the variables using a standard deviation with `n` instead of `n-1` denominator.

```
mysd <- function(y) sqrt(sum((y-mean(y))^2)/length(y))
sx <- scale(x,scale=apply(x, 2, mysd))
sx <- as.matrix(sx, ncol=20, nrow=100)
sy <- as.vector(scale(y, scale=mysd(y)))
max(abs(colSums(sx*sy)))/100
## [1] 0.1758808
fitGLM <- glmnet(sx,sy)
max(fitGLM$lambda)
## [1] 0.1758808
```

For the unscaled (original) `x` and `y`, the maximum lambda should be

```r
mysd <- function(y) sqrt(sum((y-mean(y))^2)/length(y))
sx <- scale(x,scale=apply(x, 2, mysd))
norm(t(sx) %*% y, 'i') / nrow(x) 
## [1] 0.1975946
# norm of infinity is also equal to 
max(abs(colSums(sx*y)))/100
## [1] 0.1975946
max(fitGLM$lambda) - norm(t(sx) %*% y, 'i') / nrow(x)
## [1] 2.775558e-17
```

Comment: Was the second part of the question answered here?

Comment: this only seems to answer the computations for the lambda path given that x and y are scaled on beforehand. How is the lambda path computed given that x and y are given as is?

Answer (score 5):

It seems `lambda_max` for a logistic regression is calculated similarly as for linear regression, but with weights based on class proportions:

```
set.seed(1)
library("glmnet")
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y <- rnorm(100)

mysd <- function(y) sqrt(sum((y-mean(y))^2)/length(y))
sx <- scale(x, scale=apply(x, 2, mysd))
sx <- as.matrix(sx, ncol=20, nrow=100)

y_bin <- factor(ifelse(y<0, -1, 1))
prop.table(table(y_bin)) 
# y_bin
#   -1    1 
# 0.62 0.38 
fitGLM_log <- glmnet(sx, y_bin, family = "binomial")
max(fitGLM_log$lambda)
# [1] 0.1214006
max(abs(colSums(sx*ifelse(y<0, -.38, .62))))/100
# [1] 0.1214006
```

Answer (score 3):

For your second question, look to Friedman et al's paper, ["Regularization paths for generalized linear models via coordinate descent"](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i01). In particular, see equation (10), which is equality at equilibrium. Just check under what conditions the numerator $S(\cdot,\cdot)$ is zero for all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, been a while, but maybe still of help:

You can calculate the maximum lambda value for any problem with L1-regularization by finding the highest absolute value of the gradient of the objective function (i.e. the score function for likelihoods) at the optimized parameter values for the completely regularized model (eg. all penalized parameters set to zero).

I sadly can't help with the difference in values, though. Although I can say that I try to use a max lambda value that is a bit higher - say 5% -  than the calculated maximum lambda, so that the model with all selected parameterers constrained will surely be a part of the number of estimated models. Maybe this is what is being done in glmnet.

Edit: sorry, I confused the non-regularized with the fully penalized model. Edited it above now.

Answer (score 0):

According to `help("glmnet")` the maximal lambda value is "the smallest value for which all coefficients are zero":

```
sum(fitGLM$beta[, which.max(fitGLM$lambda)])
#[1] 0
sum(glmnet(x,y, lambda=max(fitGLM$lambda)*0.999)$beta)
#[1] -0.0001809804
```

At a quick glance the value seems to be calculated by the Fortran code called by `elnet`.

Comment: Thanks, I know that the maximal lambda is the smallest value for which coefficients are zero.  I have also tried browsing through the fortran code on GitHub, unfortunately Fortran is so foreign to me I can't understand it at all...