# glmnet 4.0 negative binomial regression: "Error in seq.default(log(lambda_max), log(lambda_max * lambda.min.ratio), : 'from' must be a finite number"

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I am trying to run a negative binomial regression using the [glmnet 4.0 package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.0). I have implemented the regression using code from the section entitled 'Fitting Other GLMs' of this [webpage](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnetFamily.html). However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(log(lambda_max), log(lambda_max * lambda.min.ratio), : 'from' must be a finite number
```

I haven’t been able to find examples of other people experiencing this error in the past. I think maybe because it is specific to this new version of the package?

Below is an example which should reproduce the error. This is not the data I have been using for my analysis and is simply for example purposes.

```
library(eventdataR)
library(glmnet)
library(MASS)

df <- subset(traffic_fines, activity == "Create Fine" | activity == "Add penalty" )
df <- df[,c(4,6,7,9,13,14,18)]
df$resource <- as.numeric(df$resource)
dfm <- as.matrix(df[,-3])

newfit <- glmnet(dfm, df$amount, family = negative.binomial(theta = 5))
```

Does anyone know why this error might be occurring and what I can do to stop it?

Comment: perhaps edit your second link above to get us to a document with pg 5. Otherwise not finding `negative.binomial` in the `glmnet` `glm` family tree.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Chris. I have edited it to include an appropriate link.

Comment: so if you `debugonce(glmnet)` and step through debug `n`, you'll throw your error. At each `n` your can `ls()` and check values. What I don't see is how/where `lambda_max` is set. `lambda.min.ratio` has a default set, but seq.default can't start with `NULL`, even as log.

Comment: plenty of stuff here [glmnet computes lambda_max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257780/how-does-glmnet-compute-the-maximal-lambda-value), and normalized values.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot Chris! I'll have a look into those solutions.

Comment: I see the same issue with all R defined `family` objects - even `gaussian()`. If anyone has a found an easy solution to this, I would love to understand what it is.

Comment: The `gaussian()` family object does work for their example data.

Comment: I've come across this issue when defining the family. I think the issue is that if any combination of independent variables are a linear combination of the intercept (i.e., 1) for all rows, then the error is encountered. I'm guessing lambda = 0 might be in the search space in those cases, which would make sense as to why the model failed (infinite solutions). I'm not 100% confident about this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provided, there are no rows with no NAs,

```
table(complete.cases(df))

FALSE 
14635
```

If we chose some other columns:

```
df <- subset(traffic_fines, activity == "Create Fine" | activity == "Add penalty" )
df <- df[,c("points","article","amount","resource")]
df = df[complete.cases(df),]
df$resource <- as.numeric(df$resource)
dfm <- as.matrix(df[,-3])
```

It will run

```
newfit <- glmnet(dfm, df$amount, family = negative.binomial(theta = 5))

newfit

Call:  glmnet(x = dfm, y = df$amount, family = negative.binomial(theta = 5)) 

   Df  %Dev  Lambda
1   0  0.00 0.46180
2   1  8.23 0.42070
3   1 14.92 0.38340
4   1 20.42 0.34930
```